# Strange Shader Loading Error LWJGL 3

Tags: java, opengl, graphics, lwjgl

I have recently made a  project using LWJGL 3 but have run into a wall. I have looked all over but cannot seem to figure out why calling `GL20.glShaderSource(shaderId, shaderCode)` and then subsiquently `GL20.glCompileShader(shaderId)` returns an error. The error that I receive makes it appear as though lwjgl cannot discern the path to the shader files:

```
LWJGL Version 3.1.2 build 13
java.lang.Exception: ERROR COMPILING SHADER CODE: VERTEX SHADER FAILED TO 
COMPILE WITH THE FOLLOWING ERRORS:
ERROR: 0:1: ERROR(#132) SYNTAX ERROR: "/" PARSE ERROR
ERROR: ERROR(#273) 1 COMPILATION ERRORS.  NO CODE GENERATED


at com.wilby.model.ShaderProgram.createShader(ShaderProgram.java:47)
at com.wilby.model.ShaderProgram.createVertexShader(ShaderProgram.java:24)
at com.wilby.Renderer.initialise(Renderer.java:62)
at com.wilby.Game.initialise(Game.java:46)
at com.wilby.Game.loop(Game.java:23)
at com.wilby.Main.run(Main.java:27)
at com.wilby.Main.main(Main.java:16)
```

However it still makes this error even when the files do not need any prefix to reach it. Like I say, I am completely stumped.

The link to my project is [here](https://github.com/dannowilby/My-Game).

Comment: Are you sure that your driver deals with OpenGL 4.5? Try setting a lower version at context/window creation and inside shaders.

Comment: Yes, I know it uses OpenGL 4.5, and even so I tested it with lower settings, but still got the same error.

Comment: Show the shader and the code that produces this error. Is the first line of the shader a comment?

Comment: The error is not the shader, I think, because of how OpenGl cannot parse the file. The first line of the shader is its version. I have a link to my github above.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. You have to read the file and use that as the string in the shader source method. Facepalm.